# How import fontello in react

Tags: reactjs, fontello

I'm following this tutorial to [import](https://medium.com/@adebalanced02/using-fontello-with-react-6bdc32b3c868) fontello in my project.

But in step 5 I dont have fontello.css file.

> So, in your App.js import fontello
>
> import "./fontello/css/fontello.css"

As you can see in my project I dont have that file. So How Can I Import Fontello to my project??

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well it seems like the cli actually set all your file names in css starting with `my-icon` instead of `fontello`

To make you code work, you can import the css like

```
import "./fontello/css/my-icons.css"
```

and it should work the same

**EDIT:**

Another solution if for you to set the name field in `config.json` to `fontello` and then run `fontello-cli install`, this will lead to the css file names to be prefixed with the name `fontello` and you can import it like it is mentioned in the medium article